# Why do dynamically linked imports (in Windows) always load at application start up time?

Tags: windows, dll, load, static-libraries

One benefit of dynamically linking to a library is that when a function from that library is called, it is loaded into the virtual address space of the program, then the function is called. Statically linking loads the entire executable, taking up space.

On windows, when a program is being loaded, all of the function imports are resolved even before the program entry point gets called. Ex: `kernel32.dll!VirtualFree`. All the needed libraries are loaded, then the program's entry point is called.

How is this any different from a statically linked executable? Won't it take up the same amount of space if all the referenced libraries are loaded at once? What is the benefit? Please help me understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In point of fact, it is *not* necessary for all the DLLs on which a Windows
application depends to be loaded when it starts. Since Visual C++ 6.0 (1998),
the [MS linker has supported the `/DELAYLOAD` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls?view=vs-2019)
that defers the loading of a DLL until and unless one of its exports is called.

The default behaviour is to load DLLs at startup. I'll assume that you are wondering
how that default behaviour trades off against linking static libraries in terms of
memory footprint and more generally.

Suppose that the same API with the same implementation is built as static
library `libfoo.lib` and as a dynamic library `libfoo.dll`.

As long as only one program needs `libfoo.dll` at a given time, then *at least*
as much memory is consumed at that time as would consumed by the same program if
it was statically linked with `libfoo.lib`.

In fact, the program version that loads the DLL is quite likely to consume *more* memory
than the one that is linked with the static library. That is because when a DLL is loaded for the
first time, the *whole* DLL is loaded into memory. But in point of fact again, it is *not* the case that that when a program is linked against a static library the *whole* static library must merged into the executable.
A [static library](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/static-libraries/info) is simply an archive of object files, from which the linker
by default extracts only the ones that define symbols that are referenced by the program,
and links *them* into the program, ignoring the rest. So, if the program does not need all of the object files archived in `libfoo.lib`,
then the memory it would require by statically linking `libfoo.lib` would be *smaller*
than the memory it would require by dynamically linking `libfoo.dll`.

However, the memory cost starts to swing in favour of the DLL as soon as more
than one running program needs `libfoo.dll` at the same time. That is
because a DLL consists of distinct code and data sections that the loader can load separately.
Each concurrent program that needs `libfoo.dll` needs to have its own copy of
the DLL's *data*, but all of them can execute the same copy of its *code*. After
`libfoo.dll` - both code and data sections - has been loaded for the first
program that needs it, the loader only has to load new copies of its *data*
for any more concurrent programs that need it.

So when we consider the memory footprint of a whole running system, in which
many concurrent processes may require the services provided by a single library,
implementing such services in DLLs rather than static libraries is the economical
strategy.

The primary purpose of DLLs is to provide services in such a way that only one copy
of the implementing code has to be loaded no matter how many concurrent programs
are executing it.

But they have another important benefit, even for libraries that are
only likely to be used by one application. When a new release of the `foo` library is
made, providing bugfixes or enhancements, the only way this release can be deployed
to programs that have been linked with the static library `libfoo.lib` is to
relink, redistribute and reinstall all those programs. But as long as the new
release of `libfoo` preserves the existing API, nothing at all needs to be done
with programs that have been linked with `libfoo.dll`. It is only necessary to
distribute and install the new release of `libfoo.dll`, and those programs will
just load it the next time they run. Application architects may choose to
implement modules of *application-specific* functionality in DLLs precisely so
that updates of this functionality can be deployed without obliging end-users to
reinstall the application.